# Adding annotations to offline map programmatically

Tags: mapbox

I'm using `MapBox` with offline image, and i want to add annotations to
the map programmatically using the `MapBox iOS SDK`, but could not
figure it out. could someone out there give me some examples or hints?

Thanks in advance！

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample code taken from mapbox.com:

```
RMPointAnnotation *annotation = [[RMPointAnnotation alloc] initWithMapView:mapView
                                                                coordinate:mapView.centerCoordinate
                                                                  andTitle:@"Hello, world!"];

[mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```